# Alert dialog theme does not inherit `windowBackground` from activity theme

Tags: android

In my app I have this theme in the `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/neon_green</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black_17</item>
</style>
```

but the attribute `windowBackground` does not cause the dialog background to change. The dialog background color is still white. The `neon_green` highlight color does appear for the dialog text though.

Only the background color that does not change.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
        new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(act, R.style.AppTheme));
builder.setMessage("text")
        .setPositiveButton("pos ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("neg", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
        });
builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to my styles

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_17</item>
</style>
```

then I passed the styles to the builder

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(act,
                           R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```